# Координаты окна в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, геометрия, resizeevent

Подскажите как получить координаты окна в *PyQt5* или как определить его положение на экране.

Мне нужно чтобы новое окно открывалось на месте предыдущего, может есть какой-то другой способ. Пробовал через положение курсора при нажатии кнопки, но это совсем дичь получается. Спасибо!

Comment: насколько я помню `setGeometry()` принимает 4 аргумента, первые 2 из которых - положение окна в пространстве относительно левого верхнего угла(то есть 100, 100 значит отсутп в 100 по иксу и 100 по игрику от левого угла), это про определение, а получить координату объекта можно методом `.x()`, `.y()`

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось сделать через `.x()` и `.y()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получить координат окна и определения его положение на экране
хорошо подходит `frameGeometry : const QRect` -
геометрия виджета относительно его родителя, включая любую рамку окна.

Другое дело когда вы собираетесь отслеживать местоположение
окна на экране.

Попробуйте пример, измените его размер,
а также попробуйте перетащить окно не изменяя его размер.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimeLine, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.w = self.size().width()
        print(self.w)

        self.label = QLabel('<h2 style="color: blue;">Hello PyQt5</h2>', self)
        self.label.move(-100, 100)

        self.timeline = QTimeLine(6000*2, self)        
        self.timeline.setFrameRange(0, self.w+100)     

        self.timeline.frameChanged.connect(self.set_frame_func)
        self.timeline.setLoopCount(0)                          
        self.timeline.start()

        self.frame_geometry = None                                           # !!!

    def set_frame_func(self, frame):
        self.label.move(-100+frame, 100)
       
        if self.frame_geometry != self.frameGeometry():                      # !!!
            self.frame_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
            print(f' set_frame_func: -> {self.frame_geometry}')
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):  
        super(Demo, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.w = self.size().width()
        self.timeline.setFrameRange(0, self.w+100)
        duration = self.w * 20
        self.timeline.setDuration(duration)
        
        self.frame_geometry = self.frameGeometry()                           # !!!
        print(f'+++ releaseEvent -> {self.frame_geometry}')
      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]